# URL normalization for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, url

If I need a column to store URL and I need to have it in "normalized" form (for a comparison, etc), how to do it? Some special data type? Some functions for normalization? Good practice how to achieve it? Any hint would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [pguri](https://github.com/petere/pguri) extension will fit the bill.